# Files.lines : close stream

Tags: java

I need to close this stream created by Files.lines:

```
  Map<String, Long> wordCounts =
        Files.lines(fileP, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        .map(line -> line.replaceAll("[.?!]$"," % "))
        .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

How can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Files.lines` implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can use `try-catch` with resources.

```
try(Stream<String> fileLines = Files.lines(fileP, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))){

    Map<String, Long> wordCounts = fileLines.map(line -> line.replaceAll("[.?!]$"," % "))
                                      .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line))
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                                               TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After `try` block is executed, it automatically call `fileLines.close()`

P.S.: Read answer of `rzwitserloot`, it contains useful information.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

> [..]If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(fileP, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
    stream.map(line -> line.replaceAll("[.?!]$"," % "))
      ...//rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API of stream is not meant to be used this way. Unfortunately, streams / functional / optional etc are the current 'flavour of the day' and there are a ton of zealots and proselytisers who have found their religion and are now actively trying to convert every soul they can find. The code, as you wrote it, looks 'clean' to them (a term in the eye of the beholder, but I can see how this style of code looks good to many), and this has extended to the very oracle tutorials themselves who get this wrong all the time. The javadoc is explicit on how you are supposed to use streams, however. And this isn't how.

From the javadoc of `Files.lines`:

> The returned stream encapsulates a Reader. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

This is a flippant remark; 'if timely disposal of file system resources is required' is a funny way of saying 'if you want your VM to not become borderline useless because it ran out of file handles and is at risk of crashing due to not even being able to open a jar file to read in some classes'.

Thus, you must do what it says: wrap them in try-with-resources blocks. Any `Stream` can be so wrapped (because `Stream` implements AutoClosable - it has a `close()` method):

```
Map<String, Long> wordCounts;
try (var stream = Files.lines(fileP)) {
    wordCounts = stream
      .map(...)
      .flatMap(...)
      .collect(...);
}
```

NB: Specifying UTF-8 is not needed here; unlike most base methods in the java core runtime, all `Files` methods that implicitly convert bytes to chars or vice-versa will use UTF-8 if you fail to specify an encoding.

NB2: Terminal operations on stream, such as `.collect`, do end up closing the underlying stream when they are done. The problem is: Your stream will remain unclosed if e.g. one of your `.map` operations ends up throwing.